# Connect to namedpipeserver from remote computer

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I want to use namedpipeserver/client to communicate between two applications on two computers in a network. This network is a SOHO architecture, so security is of a lesser concern, we're just currently trying to get the system up and running.

I have written an Taskbar Application that opens up a server (on computer A) and a winform application that connects to the server (on computer B). Running both on the same computer gives me a functional interaction.

Trying it on two machines gives the error "System.IO.IOException: "Der Benutzername oder das Kennwort ist falsch." (in english: "The user or password are incorrect")

I have already searched high and low and found a few interesting articles such as:

[Setting named pipe security in a Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144093/setting-named-pipe-security-in-a-domain)

[Named pipe client unable to connect to server running as Network Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852558/named-pipe-client-unable-to-connect-to-server-running-as-network-service)

[NamedPipeClientStream can not access to NamedPipeServerStream under session 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174660/namedpipeclientstream-can-not-access-to-namedpipeserverstream-under-session-0)

[Named Pipes Across Network Gives "The user name or password is incorrect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863392/named-pipes-across-network-gives-the-user-name-or-password-is-incorrect)

I changed my security settings for the server accordingly:

```
        PipeSecurity pipeSa = new PipeSecurity();
        // Set the pipesecurity
        pipeSa.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
                        PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));
        // Alternative with "everyone"
        // pipeSa.SetAccessRule(@"Jeder", PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

        serverPipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(
            pipeName,
            PipeDirection.InOut,
            NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,
            PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
            PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
            10,
            10,
            pipeSa);
```

Alas without success. I also checked the port settings for the firewalls on both machines and cannot connect. Any hints on how to troubleshoot this issue further or what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120124/how-to-use-named-pipes-over-network Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Not really, I wasn't able to relate the information. If it is the server name: I tried the network name as well as an IP, to no success.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
var account = (NTAccount)sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
var rule = new PipeAccessRule(
    account.ToString(), 
    PipeAccessRights.FullControl, 
    AccessControlType.Allow);
var securityPipe = new PipeSecurity();
securityPipe.AddAccessRule(rule);

var pipeserver = new NamedPipeServerStream(
    Name, 
    PipeDirection.InOut, 
    NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, 
    PipeTransmissionMode.Message, 
    PipeOptions.None, 
    0, 
    0, 
    securityPipe)
```

Work fine for me.